# FEM in Mathematica and AceGen

Tags: finite-element-method

I just wanted to ask, if anybody has already worked with AceGen

[AceGen, Wolfram Research](http://www.wolfram.com/products/applications/acegen/)

[AceGen, Homepage](http://www.fgg.uni-lj.si/Symech/)

and knows what **clear advantages** AceGen has compared to the new FEM in Mathematica 10 (besides creating code in C, FORTRAN or MATLAB and automatic differentiation). I just have the feeling that the new FEM in Mathematica 10 and later in 11 or 12 may cover all functionalities of AceGen and I dont see any real advantage in spending time with it.

Comment: AceGen is a numerical code generator, somewhat similar (I suppose) to MathCode. Probably you should change your question to refer to AceFEM?

Comment: My understanding of AceGen is that you write a weak form of a PDE and the generate code. The Mathematica FEM code is designed that in principal you should not need to know that the underlying discretization is FEM and as such does not provide direct access to the weak form.

Comment: @OleksandrR. thank you, I am really not very familiar with this AceGen and AceFem stuff. But I think you are right, with AceGen I am only able to generate the code of an algorithm and export it to several languages. I mean, as far as I understood it until now, you could even write the algorithms for element types and export it to a the language you need.